# Rails AASM (Acts as State Machine) on_transition callback blocks transition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aasm

My event signature is

```
event :accepted do
  transitions :from => :created, :to => :scheduled, :on_transition => :driver_accepted_ride, :after => :notify_scheduled
end
```

on transition callback is

```
def driver_accepted_ride( driver )
  Rails.logger.debug 'on transition driver accepted ride'
  self.driver = driver 
  self.car = driver.car
  save   
end
```

and called as

```
ride.accepted(driver)
```

yet I get the error:

```
Event 'accepted' cannot transition from 'created'
```

why would this be so?   Removing the `on_transition` callback allows the transition to proceed. I would like to pass values to the `on_transition` callback.

Comment: The [documentation](https://github.com/aasm/aasm) uses a `Proc` for the `on_transition`, or is there some other way to define it?

Comment: also docs say that Proc is no longer necessary to define on_transition, it can defined with :symbol, which works for the other callbacks.  I don't think the using Proc would make a difference, but could I be wrong about that?

Comment: Oh, I don’t see that. I can’t be sure, but I suspect the problem is that the method is being called without arguments. But I don’t understand why they pass two parameters in the documentation and the method only receives one. So… I’m no help, I think!

Comment: the docs contain a deprecated form where the current state needed to be passed as the first argument (this has been removed from the current implementation)  i tried this too, and got the same error.

Comment: looks like the problem may be a misunderstanding on my side.. according to the docs, callbacks are registered with the event, not with the transitions within an event.

Comment: Which version of AASM are you using? Using :on_transition with a transition is totally fine, but if you want to provide the driver with the event trigger, as an argument to the :on_transition callback, you have to call accepted(nil, driver). This is cumbersome and I removed it in AASM version 4 (which is not yet released).

Comment: ah maybe that is the problem. I read that the extra nil param had been removed, but thought it was already released.

Comment: yup needed the nil param.